# Queried class member returns wrong value

Tags: c++, dll, raii

I have created a simple RAII class in one of my DLLs (let's call it the `exporting` DLL) which monitors for configuration restore in my application:

---

#### Header file

```
class __declspec(dllexport) CEmuConfigurationRestoreMonitor
{
public:
    CEmuConfigurationRestoreMonitor()
    {
        m_restoreInProgress = true;
    }

    ~CEmuConfigurationRestoreMonitor()
    {
        m_restoreInProgress = false;
    }

    static bool IsRestoreInProgress()
    {
        return m_restoreInProgress;
    }

private:
    static bool m_restoreInProgress;
};
```

#### Source file

```
bool CEmuConfigurationRestoreMonitor::m_restoreInProgress = false;
```

---

The idea is that the restore code in the `exporting` DLL will instantiate a `CEmuConfigurationRestoreMonitor` on the stack and when it goes out of scope at the end of the method, the flag will be switched off.

The problem is that I want to query the flag, using `IsRestoreInProgress()`, from another DLL (let's say the `importing` DLL).  This is why I put `__declspec(dllexport)` in the class declaration in the `exporting` DLL.

When I link the `importing` DLL, I got an unresolved symbol for `m_restoreInProgress`.  So I added the following line to a .cpp file in the `importing` DLL and it fixes that issue:

```
bool CEmuConfigurationRestoreMonitor::m_restoreInProgress = false;
```

What I am finding now is that even if `m_restoreInProgress` is set to `true`, when I query it from the `importing` DLL, it's always returning `false`.

Is the static initialization in the `importing` DLL somehow overriding the real (current) value in the `exporting` DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given each DLL its own copy of m_restoreInProgress.

You could fix this by:

- Not using an inline function.
- Using a file-scoped variable for m_resotreInProgress, in a source file included in only the exporting DLL.

Comment: +1 Thanks, moving the method definitions into the `.cpp` file fixed my problem.